# Nested for-loop complexity

Tags: time, complexity-theory

What is the growth function of every case (a-d)? 
I struggle to find the running time of each nested for loop. I guess I have found some of them but I am not sure.

**a)**

```
for(i = 1; i*i <= N; i = 2*i);
```

**b)**

```
for(i = 1; i <= N; i = 2*i);
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j = j+1);
```

**c)**

```
for(i = 1; i*i <= N; i=i+1);
    for(j=1; j <= i ; j=j+1);
```

**d)**

```
for(i = 1; i*i <= N; i=i+1)
    for(j = 1; j <= i ; j = 2*j);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How long each iteration of for loop takes?

Comment: What about the complexity? Your question is still unclear. You want to know which one of those for loop (a - d) is the most complex or something?

Comment: No, for every of them, I would like to find the growth function.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I got:

**Growth:**

1. `O(log(sqrt(N)))`
2. `O(N)`
3. `O(N)`
4. `O(log(sqrt(N)!)) = O(sqrt(N)*log(sqrt(N)))` using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

**Exact numbers:** (`[X]` is the integer part of X)

1. `[log([sqrt(N)])]+1`
2. `2^([log(N)]+1)`
3. `[sqrt(N)]*[sqrt(N)+1]/2`
4. not really sure.

And here's a little check: I implemented the for loops with a counter, this is the output for `N=10000000`:

```
a(N)= 12           a(10*N)= 14
b(N)= 16777216     b(10*N)= 134217728
c(N)= 5000703      c(10*N)= 50005000
d(N)= 33861        d(10*N)= 123631
```

**EDIT**: as requested, explanations
First of all, some consideration:

- we are treating integers, so of any real function you see (`sqrt` and `log` basically) you should actually take the integer part.
- as almost always in computer science, `log = log base 2`

Now:

1. `i` goes from 1 to `sqrt(N)`, but it does so "using" only powers of 2. There are `log(M)` (+1 actually) powers of 2 between 1 and M, so with `M = sqrt(N)` you get the formula.
2. `i` goes from `1` to `N` by powers of 2, as before. For every `i` there are `i` js. If we sum the js for every `i`:
   `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + 2^log(N) = 2N - 1 = O(N)`
3. `i` goes from `1` to `sqrt(N)`. For each `i`, there are `i` js. As before we sum the number of js for each `i`:
   `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + sqrt(N) = sqrt(N) * sqrt(N+1) / 2  = O(N)`
4. `i` goes from `1` to `sqrt(N)`. For every `i`, `j` goes from `1` to `i` using only powers of 2, therefore for every `i` you have `log(i)` js. If you sum all the js for every i you get:

   `log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + log(4) + log(5) + ... + log(sqrt(N))`
   For the property of logarithms `log(a) + log(b) = log(a*b)`. Apply this to our summation:
   `log(1*2*3*4*5*..*sqrt(N)) = log( sqrt(N)! )`
   Which is the result. Given that the factorial is a problem for large numbers, you can use Stirling's approximation: `ln(N!) -> N*log(N) - N` for large numbers.

**Example of the difference using integer part**

Consider 2. The integer part of `log(N)` stays the same until `N` doubles. Which means, for example, that this `for` cycle execs the same number of operations (`131072`) for `N=65536` and for N=`131071`. When `N` becomes `131072` (just one more), the number of operations doubles (`262144`).

Answer (score 1):

You can formally solve the code fragments using Sigma Notation:

**a)**

[image]

**b)**

[image]

**c)**

[image]

**d)**

[image]